# 64 bit now recommended?

Tags: 64-bit

For the longest time 64 bit was not recommended, now we see that 13 has a 64 bit option and the not recommended message has been removed from the downloads page.  Does this mean that I can run 64 on a 64 cpu without problems, please advise.

Comment: You've always been able to run 64-bit on a 64-bit cpu without any issues....

Comment: I am running Ubuntu 13.04 64 bits without any problems and I also use an ATI HD 5870 with its proprietary driver, Eclipse Kepler, Firefox 64 bits, and many others common software without having any problems, also the 32 bits applications install normally. I think yes, the 13.04 64 bits version is recommended. PS. I had no problems that are exclusive of this.

Comment: Unless there is some exotic software that you must run and it does not work on 64 bit, the answer is **yes**. For normal use, 64 bit is fine. Unless you tell us about specific concerns with any particular software, the OS has been running fine for quite sometime.

Comment: This question is the exact reverse of the other one.  Voting to reopen.

Comment: Just a thought: It might have played a role, that there was no 64bit flash plugin until last year,  and 64bit browsers cannot use 32bit plugins. Therefore 64bit users had to fight with nspluginwrapper to get flash working.... Apart from such plugin issues, 64bit worked as well as 32bit, and since multiarch was enabled also the compatibility with 32bit apps is  excellent.

Comment: Not to mention that 64bit will efficiently utilized RAM rather than 32bit system. Most 64bit architecture will make fully used of system RAM thus making the system more stable, faster and secure...

Answer (score 1):

### 64 bit now recommended?

It is not *not recommended* anymore. The website probably got tweaked but could already have been changed for 12.10. Seems someone got annoyed by it and changed the website...

### Does this mean that I can run 64 on a 64 cpu without problems, please advise?

As far as I am aware you could always run it. The 32bit version of Ubuntu will run on a 32bit CPU and a 64bit CPU. The 64bit version of Ubuntu will run on a 64bit CPU. It was recommended for users who would not know or care about the difference. But the change to [multiarch](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MultiArch) was a big improvement.

> Multiarch is a new approach to running programs compiled for one computer architecture on another, particular i386<->amd64 (see [32bit and 64bit](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/32bit%20and%2064bit) for an explanation to these two architectures). If Ubuntu is working, you should not have to concern yourself with the details of how it supports different computer architectures; just install the programs you like.
>
> [Multiarch](http://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO) lets you install library packages from multiple architectures on the same machine. This is useful in various ways, but the most common is installing both 64 and 32-bit software on the same machine and having dependencies correctly resolved automatically. In general you can have libraries of more than one architecture installed together and applications from one architecture or another installed as alternatives. Note that it does not enable multiple architecture versions of applications to be installed simultaneously.